# Showing a new element when window has scrolled past another element

Tags: jquery, css, fixed

I seem to be having some problems with my jquery code on getting my cloned navigation to come into view once the user has scrolled past a particular element in the page and then if they scroll back up it animates out again.

The jquery code i've written is:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
var homeHeight = $('#header').outerHeight() + $('.homeIntro').outerHeight();
var scrollPosition = $(this).scrollTop(); 
if( homeHeight <= scrollPosition ) {
    $('#clonedHeader').animate({'top': '0'}, 300);      
} else {
    $('#clonedHeader').animate({'top': '-100px'}, 300); 
}
```

});

Here's a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ABdLh/

So theres a cloned header that slides into view when you scroll past the homeIntro part, well thats the idea that i want, but its not happening for me!

Any help would be much appreciated! thanks!

Comment: You didn't add the jQuery library in your fiddle. I've updated it: http://jsfiddle.net/ABdLh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I overlooked some code previously. By simply adding the `.stop()`-method you can get it to work:

```
if(homeHeight <= scrollPosition) {
    $('#clonedHeader').stop().animate({'top': '0'}, 300);      
} else {
    $('#clonedHeader').stop().animate({'top': '-100px'}, 300); 
}
```

Try it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PG3wx/).

Comment: That'll be it, seems to work perfectly! :-) 

I only missed off the jquery becuase i was rushing, it was all there in my local version just not on the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Yup that (jQuery not selected) was the core problem for why it wasn't working. But a few suggestions --

Duplicating html markup like this is really bad. You should use jQuery/CSS to adjust what the header looks like at various scroll positions.

Also, it might help you debug a bit if you use the console in Chrome/Firefox -- it would of given you errors right away without jQuery. And if you open up my fiddle here, I left console.log() statements in there to show where the functions get fired based on scroll.

Animating a header like this is going to lead a bunch of problems. Using jQuery animations could cause a build up problem if you scroll up and down really quickly, which could cause the same header to be on the page at the same time. *NOTE -- The stop method you mentioned will help with this, but for most animation problems (specifically with hover), it won't be sufficient and you should look into a plugin like 'HoverIntent'.*

Last, its good practice to declare + calculate as many variables as you can outside of a function that gets constantly updated -- you don't need to continuously recalculate the height of the header that you are comparing to, it will be a fixed number.

```
// this height will be the same, you dont need to constantly calculate it on scroll
var homeHeight = $('#header').outerHeight() + $('.homeIntro').outerHeight(),
    scrollPosition;

$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    scrollPosition = $(this).scrollTop();
    animateHeight(scrollPosition);
});

function animateHeight(scrollPosition) {
    if (scrollPosition >= homeHeight) {
        console.log('yes');
        $('#clonedHeader').animate({
            'top': '0'
        }, 300);
    } else {
        console.log('no');
        $('#clonedHeader').animate({
            'top': '-100px'
        }, 300);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ndreckshage/ecUAc/

Comment: hoverIntent won't help here, just need some throttling of calling the animations and using flag for current setting . If conditions haven't changed based on flag no need to call animation

Comment: Thanks for all of those suggestions, I only missed the jquery library on the fiddle, it was there in my local version, that'll teach me to rush! 

I've got jquery cloning the header for me as it causes a very awkward jump if it uses the same header to fix to the top of the page, I tried a number of different ways but found this to work easiest. 

That's some very good points about the console logging, I will definitely modify my code to take that into account. Thanks a lot for all the advice, I definitely need to polish up on my js, big time